# Liquibase - checksum differs with different database vendors

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, liquibase

I have a problem with Liquibase checksum when I try to run it on MSSQL and MySQL.

In my MSSQL-base I have a changelog-entry with this checksum:

```
3:cf2f5de7a1dcc738bbc185e25fbcf6c9
```

When I run my liquibase against this database, it works just fine.

Then, I copy the changelog-entry to my MySQL-database and try to run, and get this error:

```
myLiquibase.xml::1::Tobb is now: 3:cedf7a8ba54ea3f83141f79
```

I have tried setting the checksum to `null` in my MSSQL in order to regenerate the checksum, and the checksum reverts back to

```
3:cf2f5de7a1dcc738bbc185e25fbcf6c9
```

When doing the same in MySQL, i get this checksum:

```
3:cedf7a8ba54ea3f83141f7987007deb7
```

So, from what I can see, depending on whether it's run in MSSQL or MySQL, Liquibase generates a different checksum. How can this happen? I thought the checksum was only dependant on the actual content of the liquibase-script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it depends on content and **DB type**, because actually checksum depends not on your `changeset` text, but on **sql** which is generated for current DB, which will slightly different for different DBs.

If you want to avoid checksum erros, you can use `validCheckSum` tag in changesets.

Comment: I see, but `validCheckSum` will disable the checksum checking all together? It will remove some of the safety in knowing that a script has been run in it's current state..

Answer (score 0):

The checksum is actually computed based on a normalized version of the changeset text, not the SQL and should be unrelated to the database type.

Are you running on different OS versions for the different databases?

Comment: MySQL is running locally, on Windows7 64-bit. MSSQL is running on Windows Server 2008 R2. We are using version 2.0.1 of Liquibase. Might it be due to overriding of datatypes?

Comment: Thanks, Windows 7 vs. 2008r2 shouldn't affect the checksum. How are you overriding datatypes? Just allowing liquibase to convert them as it normally does, or using changelog parameters?

Comment: We are using the modifySql-element: `<modifySql dbms="mysql">
      <replace replace="NUMBER(19,0)" with="bigint(20)"/>
    </modifySql>`

Comment: OK. I don't remember how that affected checksums in 2.0 but  may be the issue. If you use <validCheckSum> like @Andremoniy suggested you can just list the checksums that are known to be valid and it will still fail on all others.

Comment: It's not a huge number of changes, I got through by manually making sure that all changes were in effect (it's a local database, so schema is generated by Hibernate), and then null-ing out all the checksums so that they are set with a proper value. I guess upgrading Liquibase-version should be on my list of TODOs..