# different checksums against different database versions of mssql

Tags: liquibase

I've got a bit of a problem with my liquibase changeSets.

If I run my changeSet against an MSSQL 2008 database schema, liquibase will generate a checksum (lets call it 'x').
When I run my changeSet against an MSSQL 2012 database schema, liquibase will generate (for some of my changesets) a different checksum ('y').

Examples of changesets which create different checksums:

```
<changeSet author="Camilla" id="25c">
       <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
           <dbms type="db2" />
       </preConditions>

       <comment>extend column abc within table def (db2)</comment>
       <sql >
           ALTER TABLE def ALTER COLUMN abc SET DATA TYPE ${P_VARCHAR}(8)
       </sql>

       <update tableName="VERSION">
           <column name="V_NO" value="0.03"/>
       </update>
   </changeSet>

 <changeSet author="Camilla" id="22">
    <comment>add default value column for mapping</comment>
    <addColumn tableName="MAPPING">
        <column name="M_DEF" type="${P_VARCHAR}(256)"/>
    </addColumn>

    <update tableName="VERSION">
        <column name="V_NO" value="0.027"/>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

Now if I start with 2008 and then upgrade the installation to 2012, the checksums do not match anymore.

I tried to solve the problem by using 'validCheckSum'.
At first I thought, I need to place the checksums there which might be in the database (which would have been x) and that liquibase will simply update that x to the newly computed value y.
But then I found the discussion [understanding validCheckSum](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/understanding-validchecksum) and recognised that it was the other way around. I would have to place y within validCheckSum and then any value within the database will be ignored.

But then again I found topic [liquibase-checksum-differs-with-different-database-vendors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928628/liquibase-checksum-differs-with-different-database-vendors) and Nathan suggests

> If you use 'validCheckSum' like @Andremoniy suggested you can just list the checksums that are known to be valid and it will still fail on all others. –  Nathan Voxland Sep 24 '14 at 16:02

But I can't confirm that behaviour. If I add `<validCheckSum>y</validCheckSum>` to my changeset and change my 'x' within the Database to 'z', liquibase will just go about and ignore that 'z'. The consequence is, that I will never be aware of manipulations within the entries of the databasechangelog (e.g. people copying entries from a different schema in there because "they know what they are doing").

As I understand it, the 'validCheckSum' is only suitable for those cases, where I want to protect myself from accidentially changing a change set that might have been used. But I can't use it in cases I want to make sure the databasechangelog isn't manipulated.

That leaves me to the only alternative to NULL the checksums in the database once I know that the databaseversion changed from 2008 to 2012. In this case, I loose the crosscheck from database checksum to generated one just once.

Or is there another way I could achive my goal?

The other question is why it makes a difference running against 2008 and 2012.
I use changelog parameters:

```
    liquibase.setChangeLogParameter("P_CHAR", getCharDataType());
    liquibase.setChangeLogParameter("P_VARCHAR", getVarcharDataType());
    liquibase.setChangeLogParameter("P_INT", getIntegerDataType());
    liquibase.setChangeLogParameter("P_LONG", getLongDataType());

    liquibase.setChangeLogParameter("P_DEFAULT_SCHEMA_NAME", defaultSchemaName);
```

with liquibase-core 2.0.5

Interesting enough **this** changeset does not generate different checksums:

```
<changeSet author="Camilla" id="17">
    <comment>Added column 'in test mode' (TST) to table </comment>
    <addColumn tableName="EXAMPLE">
        <column name="TST" type="${P_INT}" defaultValueNumeric="0"/>
    </addColumn>

    <update tableName="VERSION">
        <column name="V_NO" value="0.022"/>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

It seems to be a problem if I have used ${P_CHAR} or ${P_VARCHAR} in the changeSet. But the value which is provided there, will be equal in both cases because it will only vary between NCHAR/CHAR, which is defined within the configuration of my system and won't change with the database version.

Oh, by the way. I glanced over the checksums generated for DB2 and it seems to be the case, that they are the same as the ones generated for 2008.

Thanks,
Camilla

Answer (score 0):

Normally Liquibase doesn't consider the database when computing checksums, only the XML itself. You are seeing the differences because of the changelog parameters changing the XML to checksum. The issue with parameters in attributes not changing the checksum has been addressed in 3.x, so if you upgrade you will see a difference in there as well.

Your only two options are to use validCheckSum or null out the problem rows from DATABASECANGELOG when upgrading the database.

ValidCheckSum is the normal approach, where you list both X and Y checksums since you know those permutations are correct. It doesn't address the issue of someone unexpectedly changing the checksum in the DATABASECHANGELOG table, but I'm not sure a use case where that will normally happen.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the clarification. I will try to update and see what happens with my checksums.

Comment: (I've been to slow to edit my previous comment)
The though about crosschecking with the db values comes from my experience with some guys of professional services. They are always quick to manipulate something within the database when an error occurs which just seems to be an inconvenience (like the server will not start because of the checksum error). _Without_ thinking their way through the problem first, of course. So you are right: _normally_ there is no use case for crosschecking. Hava a nice weekend, Camilla